# Total-Amount value get decrease again after first onclick

Tags: javascript

When I insert only Discount-Percentage and Total-Amount output should subtract Total-Amount and display Discount-Amount and when I insert only Discount-Amount it should only subtract Total-Amount.

After first click getting expected output but if I click again it subtracts Total-Amount value again.

How can I prevent this or is there any other way to solve this problem.

example :

- Case 1 : Discount-Percentage 6
  Total-Amount 130 And Discount-Amount 0
  Output Total-Amount 122.2 and
  Discount-Amount 7.8
- Case 2 : Discount-Amount 30
  Total-Amount 130 and Discount Percentage 0
  Output Total-Amount 100 and
  Discount-Amount 30

```js
function test() {
  var damount = document.getElementById('damount').value;
  var gt = document.getElementById('gtotal').value;
  if (damount == '0.00' || damount == '0') {
    dp = document.getElementById('dper').value;
    dsc = parseFloat((parseInt(dp) * parseFloat(gt)) / 100);
    document.getElementById('damount').value = dsc;
    damt = parseFloat(gt - dsc);
    document.getElementById('gtotal').value = damt;
  } else {
    damt = parseFloat(gt - damount);
    document.getElementById('gtotal').value = damt;
  }
}
```

```html
Discount-Percentage <input type='text' value="0.00" id="dper"><br>
Discount-Amount     <input type='text' value="0.00" id="damount"><br>
Total-Amount        <input type='text' id='gtotal'><br>
<input type='text' onclick='test();'>
```

Comment: Why onclick of a field? Why not a button?

Comment: var gt = document.getElementById('gtotal').value; every time you click

Comment: I would guess you need to chage `var gt = document.getElementById('gtotal').value;` to `var gt = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. If you have any problem just leave a comment

```js
    var gt = 0;
    var once = true;
    function changeVal()
    {
    once = true;
    }
    function getTotAmount()
    {
      if(once)
      {
      gt=document.getElementById('gtotal').value;
      once = false;
      }
    }
    function test()
    {
        //var final_txt=document.getElementById('final_txt');
        var damount=document.getElementById('damount').value;
        
        if(damount=='0.00' || damount=='0')
        {
              dp=document.getElementById('dper').value;
              dsc=parseFloat((parseInt(dp)*parseFloat(gt))/100);
              document.getElementById('damount').value=dsc;
              damt=parseFloat(gt-dsc);
              document.getElementById('gtotal').value=damt;
        }
        else
        {
              damt=parseFloat(gt-damount);
              document.getElementById('gtotal').value=damt;
        }
        //final_txt.disabled = true;
    }
```

```html
    Discount-Percentage <input type='text' value="0.00" id="dper" onclick="changeVal()"><br>
    Discount-Amount<input type='text' value="0.00" id="damount" onclick="changeVal()"><br>
    Total-Amount<input type='text' id='gtotal'><br>
    <input id="final_txt" type='text' onclick='getTotAmount();test();'>
```

Comment: If I call that function from total-amount text box then how to solve this problem